# Google One Tap Integration with Meteor

Tags: node.js, google-signin, google-authentication, meteor-accounts, google-one-tap

I am integrating a [Meteor](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html) application with Google's [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/verify-google-id-token). Attempting to use Meteor's `loginWithGoogle` in order to get the user to save to [Meteor Accounts](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html) (built into Meteor.js). The complexity of this is that

> One-Tap library is not meant to authorize the user (i.e. produce
> Access Token), only to authenticate the user

Thus, what I've had to do is authenticate the user using Google Api, or `gapi` to retrieve the necessary `access_token` and `id_token`. Props to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953745/how-to-use-the-google-api-client-for-javascript-with-a-one-tap-sign-in-flow).

What I've got so far is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div data-prompt_parent_id="g_id_onload" style={{ position: "absolute", top: "5em", right: "1em" }} id="g_id_onload"></div>
```

**CLENT SIDE**

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  prompt_parent_id: "g_id_onload",
  client_id: "42424242-example42.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  auto_select: false,
  callback: handleCredentialResponse
});

const handleCredentialResponse = async oneTapResponse => {
  // see the SERVER SIDE code, which is where validation of One Tap response happens
  Meteor.call("verifyOneTap", oneTapResponse.credential, oneTapResponse.clientId, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    if (result) {
      // Initialize the JavaScript client library.
      gapi.load("auth2", function() {
        // Ready. Make a call to gapi.auth2.init or some other API 
        gapi.auth2.authorize(
          {
            client_id: oneTapResponse.clientId,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            response_type: "code token id_token",
            prompt: "none",
            // this is the actual email address of user, example@gmail.com, passed back from the server where we validated the One Tap event...
            login_hint: result.email
          },
          function(result, error) {
            if (error) {
              // An error happened.
              console.log(error);
              return;
            }
            //these are the authentication tokens taht are so difficult to capture...
            let theAccessToken = result.access_token;
            let theIdToken = result.id_token;

            //*********************************
            //this is the part that doesn't work
            //trying to get it to create the account without another Google prompt...
            Meteor.loginWithGoogle({ accessToken: theAccessToken, idToken: theIdToken, prompt: "none" }, function(err, res) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              }
            });
            //*********************************
          }
        );
      });
    }
  });
};

google.accounts.id.prompt(notification => {
  //this just tells you when things go wrong...
  console.log(notification);
});
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");
const clientOA2 = new OAuth2Client("42424242-example42.apps.googleusercontent.com");

// the token and clientId are returned from One Tap in an object, are credential (token) and clientId (clientId)
verifyOneTap: async (token, clientId) => {
  const ticket = await clientOA2.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: token,
    audience: clientId // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = await ticket.getPayload();

  //perform validation here so you don't get hacked...

  return payload;
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  // const domain = payload['hd'];
}
```

Tried writing this in different ways on the client/server, as well as considered ways to go around this and just signing up with Meteor's [Accounts.createUser](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser), but it is less than ideal. What is wrong with the `[options]` that I am passing to `loginWithGoogle`? I would think `accessToken` and `idToken` were enough...

What happens is that on login, it does log me in through the first stage of Google One Tap, but then options that I threw into `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` are somehow not being recognized:

this works (first step of One Step flow) =>

[image: google one tap failure 2]

but then it asks for login again :|

[image: second request google one tap...]

The [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWith%3CExternalService%3E) on `loginWithGoogle` states that the format is typically:

```
Meteor.loginWith<ExternalService>([options], [callback])
```

and with regards to `loginWithGoogle`:

> options may also include [Google’s additional URI parameters](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters)

---

**Google's Additional URI Parameters**

**Required**:
client_id, nonce, response_type, redirect_uri, scope

**Optional**:
access_type, display, hd, include_granted_scopes, login_hint, prompt

---

Unfortunately, it is clearly not recognizing something in the `[options]` that I am passing, otherwise it would save the user to MongoDB, which it isn't doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found an answer - I'm working on something cleaner but this is the current fix - thank you [jimmy knoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684634/how-to-generate-new-meteor-login-tokens-server-side-in-order-to-make-a-quick-l/33367590) and [methodx](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-cant-create-new-users-accounts-createuser-undefined/24268/3) for some inspiration.

*Note: everything else same as original question above.*

**CLIENT**

```
// this is the callback from the Google One Tap `google.accounts.id.initialize` (see original Stack Overflow question above)
const handleCredentialResponse = async oneTapResponse => {
  // see the SERVER SIDE code, which is where validation of One Tap response happens
  Meteor.call("verifyOneTap", oneTapResponse.credential, oneTapResponse.clientId, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    if (result) {
      // Initialize the JavaScript client library.
      gapi.load("auth2", function() {
        // Ready. Make a call to gapi.auth2.init or some other API 
        gapi.auth2.authorize(
          {
            client_id: oneTapResponse.clientId,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            response_type: "code token id_token",
            prompt: "none",
            // this is the actual email address of user, example@gmail.com, passed back from the server where we validated the One Tap event...
            login_hint: result.email
          },
          function(tokens, error) {
            if (error) {
              // An error happened.
              console.log(error);
              return;
            }
            //gapi returns tokens including accessToken and idToken...
            Meteor.call("createOneTapUser", result, tokens, (error, stampedLoginToken) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log(error);
              }
              //this logs in with the token created earlier...should do whatever your normal google login functionality does...
            //*********************************
            // this is where you skip the Google login popup :) 
              Meteor.loginWithToken(stampedLoginToken);
            });
            //*********************************
          }
        );
      });
    }
  });
};
```

**SERVER**

```
createOneTapUser: async (userDetails, accessDetails) => {
  //just including details here for what part of a user object would look like from Meteor.loginWithGoogle > note especially resume > loginTokens
  let oneTapUserObj = {
    services: {
      google: {
        accessToken: accessDetails.access_token,
        idToken: accessDetails.id_token,
        scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "openid"], // yours may be different...
        expiresAt: accessDetails.expires_at,
        id: userDetails.sub,
        email: userDetails.email,
        verified_email: userDetails.email_verified,
        name: userDetails.name,
        given_name: userDetails.given_name,
        family_name: userDetails.family_name,
        picture: userDetails.picture,
        locale: "en"
      },
      resume: {
        loginTokens: []
      }
    } //...whatever your user object normally looks like.
  };
  //manually inserting the user
  Meteor.users.insert(oneTapUserObj);

  let newOneTapUser = await Meteor.users.findOne({ "profile.email": userDetails.email });
  // generates the login token that goes under user > services > resume > loginTokens...
  let stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
  Accounts._insertLoginToken(newOneTapUser._id, stampedLoginToken);

  //sets the social media image from the google account...you'll need to build your own...
  userDetails.picture ? scrapeSocialMediaImage(newOneTapUser._id, userDetails.picture) : console.log("Google One Tap user " + newOneTapUser._id + " has no profile picture...");

  return stampedLoginToken.token;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: I had to use `scope: "openid profile email"` in the call to gapi.auth2.authorize() in order to reliably receive name, family_name, given_name, and picture fields in the id_token response. The oneTapResponse did NOT reliably return this information for me.